# C# T4 Template equivalent for "extern alias"

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I'm looking for a way to make use of an assembly referenced by the project with an alias (i.e. other than global) from a runtime T4 template.

My goal is to be able to reference a namespace, with all its content obviously, from that assembly:

```
<#@ import namespace="CustomAlias::Target.Namespace" #>
```

Basically, I'm looking for the equivalent of writing something like:

```
extern alias CustomAlias;
using CustomAlias::Target.Namespace;
```

I've attempted searching, here and Google, and the only mention that I've found for aliases in a T4 context was about giving an alias to a namespace. Which is not my current issue.

Is  this possible to do, or should I start looking for an alternative solution?

Comment: You might be able to use `<#@ template compilerOptions="-reference:CustomAlias=SomeAssembly" #>` to do this.