# FHIR.net Property added to Practitioner

Tags: hl7-fhir

We're currently using FHIR.net library(STU3).  The FHIR Server from which we are receiving information has added a *practitionerRole* property to the Practitioner. Thus when Reading a Practitioner, we get the following Exception:

**Encountered unknown member 'practitionerRole' while de-serializing (at path 'line 1, pos 2') in Hl7.Fhir.Rest.HttpToEntryExtensions.parseResource(String bodyText, String contentType, ParserSettings settings, Boolean throwOnFormatException)**

The only solution I could think of is to add a practitionerRole property in the Model\Generated\Practitioner.cs class that would go like that:

```
    [FhirElement("practitionerRole", InSummary = true, Order = 115)]
    [Cardinality(Min = 0, Max = -1)]
    [DataMember]
    public List<Hl7.Fhir.Model.PractitionerRole> PractitionerRole
    {
        get { if (_PractitionerRole == null) _PractitionerRole = new List<Hl7.Fhir.Model.PractitionerRole>(); return _PractitionerRole; }
        set { _PractitionerRole = value; OnPropertyChanged("PractitionerRole"); }
    }

    private List<Hl7.Fhir.Model.PractitionerRole> _PractitionerRole;
```

Is there any other solution than that? If so, which one?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking to a DSTU2 server.  You'll need some sort of a conversion layer between your system and theirs.

Comment: Or, if you only need to talk to that server, you can switch to the DSTU2 library.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by FHIR employees in https://sea-region.github.com/standardhealth/shr_spec/issues/187 , DSTU2 and STU3 are two different versions of FHIR standard. If you check their last commits (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Fhir) as in August 2019, you will see they are maintaining both standards. That is probably due to the hospitals using STU3 version and do not want to adapt to the new version of FHIR, which is DSTU2.

The problem arises when you want to reach a class, let's say Patient, that coexists in two versions. Compiler can not decide which "Patient" class you refer to.

**Normally**, you could specialize using imports or predescription such as :

```
Hl7.Fhir.Model.Patient p = new Hl7.Fhir.Model.Patient();
```

**BUT**, Patient classes in both versions are described as Hl7.Fhir.Model.Patient. Their namespace is "Hl7.Fhir.Model" and their class name is "Patient".

**Normally**, you could workaround using keyword:

```
extern alias
```

**BUT**, since model classes in FHIR are read only, you can not use both versions in same project.

You need to uninstall unwanted FHIR version and install wanted version. To do these in Visual Studio,

```
go to Solution Manager> right click on "Manage Nuget Packages" > Search "Fhir" > uninstall unwanted FHIR version > install wanted version
```

You can also follow the unanswered question below:
[C# T4 Template equivalent for "extern alias"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961843/c-sharp-t4-template-equivalent-for-extern-alias)